# Why my heatmap is plotting nans if I expressly extracted the nans?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, plotly-python

I have this piece of code

```
    print(abs(data.left_error))
    print(data['left_error'].isna().sum())

    # Remove rows with NaN values in the 'left_error' column
    left_no_nan = data.dropna(subset=['left_error'])
    print(abs(left_no_nan.left_error))
    print(left_no_nan['left_error'].isna().sum())


    fig1 = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Heatmap(
            z=abs(left_no_nan.left_error),
            x=left_no_nan.somedata_left,
            y=left_no_nan['velocity'],
            colorscale='Viridis'
        )])
```

`data` has some Nan in the `left_error` column. The print output is this

> 0        0.442834
> 1        0.404161
> 2        0.361559
> 3        0.319925
> 4        0.273510
> ...
> 25405         NaN
> 25406         NaN
> 25407         NaN
> 25408         NaN
> 25409         NaN
> Name: left_error, Length: 25410, dtype: float64
> 10797
> 0        0.442834
> 1        0.404161
> 2        0.361559
> 3        0.319925
> 4        0.273510
> ...
> 25322    0.171343
> 25323    0.347305
> 25324    0.279475
> 25325    0.224612
> 25326    0.299578
> Name: left_error, Length: 14613, dtype: float64
> 0

So there are no Nan anymore in `left_no_nan`

However when I run the script I got a heatmap with a lot of Nan when I hover over it.
Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have nan in other columns
Try to:

```
left_no_nan = data.dropna(subset=['left_error', 'somedata_left', 'velocity'])
```